# pandas select rows according to condition

Tags: indexing, pandas

Suppose a pandas dataframe

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
```

How can I select all the rows such that `'a'>1, 'b'<6 and 7<='c'<=9` ?

It should result in this case equivalent to the second row of the dataframe.
In the solutions suppose a generic dataframe with `k` keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `query`

```
In [233]: d.query('a>1 and b<6 and 7<=c<=9')
Out[233]:
   a  b  c
1  2  5  8
```

Also, you could do

```
In [234]: d[(d.a>1) & (d.b<6) & (d.c>=7) & (d.c<=9)]
Out[234]:
   a  b  c
1  2  5  8
```

And, `pd.eval()` works well with expressions containing large arrays

```
In [235]: d[pd.eval('(d.a>1) & (d.b<6) & (d.c>=7) & (d.c<=9)')]
Out[235]:
   a  b  c
1  2  5  8
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer but I am still having problems. I have edited the question

Comment: Could paste few rows of data/frame?

Comment: There is a **comma** in `(dta.age3 >= low_age), (dta.bmi3>= low_bmi) &` instead of `&` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly index the dataframe, putting all conditions inside parentheses:

```
d[(d.a > 1) & (d.b < 6) & (d.c <= 9) & (d.c >= 7)]
```

For 'or' conditions, use pipe `|` between conditions.